# Java chat with transfering files

Tags: java, file, tcp, chat

I just started to learn about programming and i wanted to create chat in java where u can send files etc.
When i tried to create file transfer i got this error

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at lab03.ReadThread.run(ReadThread.java:26)
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 16 seconds)
```

here is my Client code:

```
 Thread socketReader = new ReadThread(socket);
        socketReader.start();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean files =false;
        String s="";
        while(true){
            
            if(files)
            {
                
               File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Kostar\\Desktop\\asd.txt");
               long length = file.length();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[16 * 1024];
                InputStream in2 = new FileInputStream(file);
                OutputStream out2 = socket.getOutputStream();
                        int count;
                        while ((count = in2.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                            out2.write(bytes, 0, count);
                        }

            out2.close();
            in2.close();
                
                files=false;
            }
            else
            {
                s=scanner.nextLine();
                if(s.startsWith("/sf"))
                    {
                        
                        files=true;
                        out.println(s);
                    }
                else
                    out.println(s);
            }

          
        }
        
    
     
    }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
```

And the ReadThread:

```
    public ReadThread(Socket socket) throws IOException{
    this.socket = socket;
    this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    this.out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
}
String s="";
public void run() {
    try{

        while(true){
            s=in.readLine();
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    }catch(Exception ex){   ex.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        Close();
    }
}

public void Close(){
    try{
        in.close();
        out.close();
        socket.close();  
    }catch(Exception ex){   ex.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Basically the file is created after that and it has everything what should have, but as you can see the client gets disconnected and server is receiving NULL.
Can anyone help me? I know that pasting wall of code isnt very helpfull/nice, but i think i had to

Comment: I have answered your question, but I also want to recommend that you'd probably be better of using a WebSockets framework for handling sockets, and using XML or JSON for messaging and putting together a communication protocol so that the reader knows what the incoming data is (ie string message or file)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not checking for the end of the stream. After you read from the socket, you should check your string

-- Edit --

Apologies. The advice above is correct for file reading, but not for socket reading. For sockets, you should catch the SocketException specifically. SocketException is your friend - it is how you get notified that the socket has been closed, and it frees up the thread waiting on the inputstream. I've included instructions for handling below.

```
public void run() {
    try{

        while(true){
            s=in.readLine();
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    } catch (SocketException se) {
      //potentially add a logging message that socket (socketnumber) has closed
      //socket is closed. You can exit out of the read loop
      return;
    } catch(IOException ex){   ex.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ControlAltDel, this makes the error to dissapear, but what if i dont want to close this socket? I want to send file and still be able to write something in chat

Comment: @Kostar you really need to establish a communication protocol - your own http as it were. I mention HTTP because it allows you to specify things like content-type and last-modified in the communication headers. You need something like this for the reader to know what the sender is sending.